# MongoDB - How important is the hidden property for an EBS snapshot backup secondary node?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ebs, replicaset

I have a Mongo replica set consisting of 3 nodes (1 primary, 2 secondary) running on separate AWS EC2s, using EBS.

One of the secondary nodes is a hidden dedicated backup db, and it's only task is to complete an EBS snapshot once per hour, which usually only takes 30-60 seconds to complete. It is set to `hidden: 1, priority: 0`. So the remainder of it's uptime feels wasted since it will not handle any read requests.

How important is the `hidden: 1` property in this scenario, as I know Mongo recommends setting a db as hidden when it has a different workload like this? Is there risk of read requests performance dropping, or would read requests be sufficiently redirected to the other secondary whilst backup was occurring?

Also since the backup being taken is completed by the AWS EBS volume snapshot, would this alleviate any performance hit, since the Mongo EC2 instance will have the main workset in RAM?

**Edit**

Sorry, I should have made it more clear:
Would it therefore be viable to make it visible, so that the backup db does infact handle read requests, whilst still continuing to do backups, since it is such a small period of time where the performance would drop?

Comment: When the member is HIDDEN it is not seen by the application so respectively there is no reads sent to this member by the applications at all ...

Comment: Hi thanks, I have made an edit to be a little more clear,

Would it therefore be viable to make it visible, so that the backup db does infact handle read requests, whilst still continuing to do backups, since it is such a small period of time where the performance would drop?

Comment: During snapshot backup to have consistent backup it is recommended to flush data to storage with db.fsyncLock();  to prevent writes during the backup process and respectively to unlock after the snapshot finish with db.fsyncUnlock();  , you can unhide the member , but this mean for certain operations like majority reads and writes there could be issues since those operations will not be successfull to this member during the duration of snapshot ...